# Getting trouble in fade out function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my jquery code for adding and removing **dynamic textbox along with radiobutton**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ans = 0;
    var cnt = 1;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#add").click(function () {

            //var intId = $("#abc div").length + 1;
            var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"field" + cnt + "\"/>");

                var fType = $("<input type=\"radio\" class=\"fieldtype\" id=\"Rd" + cnt + "\" name=\"RdNm\" />");
                var fName = $("<input type=\"text\" class=\"fieldname\" id=\"Txtopt" + cnt + "\"  name=\"TxtoptNm" + cnt + "\"  />");
                var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"-\" />");
                removeButton.click(function () {
                    $(this).fadeOut(1000, function () {
                        $(this).parent().remove();
                    });
                });


                fieldWrapper.append(fType);
                fieldWrapper.append(fName);
                fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
                fieldWrapper.append('<br />');
                fieldWrapper.append('<br />');

                $("#abc").append(fieldWrapper);
                $("#field" + cnt).effect("bounce", { times: 3 }, 'normal');
                //$("#Txtopt" + intId).effect("bounce", { times: 3 }, 300);
            }

            cnt = cnt + 1;

            });

        });

    </script>
```

Removing is running properly but only problem is fade out effect means when I am clicking on

Remove button then only remove button is fading out but **textbox and radio button are not fading out** though **textbox and radio button are being removed.**

How to fix this remove function?

Comment: I'd really suggest using a single quote instead of escaping the double quote for readability….

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of fading out the button and after removing the parent, if you want to fadeout the entire content obviously you should fadeout the parent altogether and then remove it. So try this instead.

```
removeButton.click(function () {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $(this).remove();
      });
  });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tZcLf/)

Comment: nope bro same problem again.only remove button is fading out.my textbox ,radio button and remove button are generating under division so for fading out i have to pass whole division then only whole thing will fade out

Comment: @user3524566 that is what i'm doing. isn't everything fading out in the demo..?

Comment: ya everything is fading out

Comment: @user3524566 any reason for accepting the answer which copy pasted my answer..? even if its not a copy paste, i gave the working answer an hour ago the other one.

Comment: sorry it was by mistake

Comment: bro can u tell me how to do i find the id of removed textbox.means suppose i am having 5 textbox and i am removing 2nd textbox then next time when i click on add button then textbox of id 2 should be generated.(Eg:id=txt2)

Comment: @TilwinJoy i already told that i did'nt copied yours first OP asked different thing, then OP said in comments that he needs to fade in different way, why are you saying that i copied yours?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad well i specifically said "even if its not a copy paste, i gave the working answer an hour ago the other one." accepting the first answer which solved the issue is the fair choice in my opinion.

Comment: @user3524566 try adding `cnt = parseInt($('.fieldname:last').attr('id').replace("Txtopt", ""));` on remove buttons click like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tZcLf/2/)

Comment: well according to first requirement that OP told mine was correct then OP said that he wants to fade all once together, well its not matter who's answer is acccepted

Comment: BTW @TilwinJoy you are so greedy for reputation that you asked OP to mark your post as answer instead of mine..haha...:d

Comment: @EhsanSajjad  Reputation system is there for a reason. You added the exact same answer as mine after an hour. So i think my answer deserves to be accepted hence i asked OP why he chose the other answer. If you don't care then why bother with this discussion..?

Comment: @TilwinJoy:bro u r realyy really genius.thanks a ton bro.thank u once again

Comment: i am just pointing out your action, i don't bother on it but the thing which is wrong is wrong, i firstly posted answer

Comment: @EhsanSajjad the answer you posted first didn't help the OP (*If it did he would've accepted the answer, i won't have posted a working solution*). The one i posted did (*You updated same thing later*). So i don't think there's anything wrong here.